# Retrofit Override Endpoint

Tags: java, retrofit

Can I override the endpoint path set on the `RestAdapter` builder?  So say I have 20 endpoints that use the same base URL, but there is 1 that does not.  I would like to call setEndpoint for all 20 to use, but override in the one case where I need to use a different base URL.

```
Builder builder = new RestAdapter.Builder().setEndpoint("http://url");
```

Use Endpoint path set on the builder:

```
 @GET("/relative
 Something getClip();
```

Use absolute path (doesn't work):

```
 @GET("http://absolute/path")
 Something getAlert();
```

Answer (score 25, accepted):

The RestAdapter will actually consult the EndPoint every time a request is made. This means that you can implement your own and pass it in the RestAdapter.  Keeping a reference to it means that you'd be able to make change the url when you need.

```java
public final class FooEndpoint implements Endpoint {
  private String url;

  public void setUrl(String url) {
    this.url = url;
  }

  @Override public String getName() {
    return "default";
  }

  @Override public String getUrl() {
    if (url == null) throw new IllegalStateException("url not set.");
    return url;
  }
}
```

Then simply do something like so

```java
FooEndPoint endPoint = new FooEndPoint();
// Keep a reference to this instance
endPoint.setUrl("url1");

RestAdapter.Builder builder = new RestAdapter.Builder();
    builder.setEndpoint(endPoint);

SomeApi api = builder.build().create(SomeApi.class);
api.getSomeDataFromUrl1();

// when needed you can update the url
endPoint.setUrl("url2");

api.getSomeDataFromUrl2();
```

Comment: having the endpoint be a single global doesn't play well with async calls. From my testing with retrofit + rx-java, it seems the endpoint is checked on subscription, rather than when the observable is constructed.

Comment: This solution is flawed. It doesn't work on asynchronous calls as mentioned by others. I added a comment in the github thread about this https://github.com/square/retrofit/issues/333#issuecomment-106339349